# How to append and retrieve data to an url using struts2 annotations?

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, struts2, struts2-jquery

Am using struts2 framework with annotations,So here is one problem that am facing that, I want to retrieve the information from Database based on the data which am appending to the URL

this is the url which am sending through ajax:

```
URL:CountryMasterftrdndcountryftrdkgCountryActioncreateCountryMastermcodeCNTRY?countryCode=IND&id=222
```

i was able to retrieve the data from url when am using xml as medium by creating setters and getters in action class.

but when am started using annotations as the mapping medium not able see the url with appended data parameters and not able to retrieve it .

eg:- when am using annotations as mapping medium

```
URL:CountryMasterftrdndcountryftrdkgCountryActioncreateCountryMastermcodeCNTRY
```

eg:- when am using xml as mapping medium

```
URL:CountryMasterftrdndcountryftrdkgCountryActioncreateCountryMastermcodeCNTRY?countryCode=IND&id=222
```

so,friends how to retrieve and append the data to an url when we are using annotations and how to retrieve it from url please help me out...

thanks in advance...

Comment: `CountryMasterftrdndcountryftrdkgCountryActioncreateCountryMastermcodeCNTRY` won the prize for the ugliest URL I've ever seen

Comment: Andrea ... it was according to our requirement though it looks ugliest to you it is well known for our company people that is enough... look at the question first if u r interested not on decorations ... please mind it ...

Comment: Kidding apart, the question makes no sense. It is about annotations, and there is not even one annotation... also, how can server-side annotations being involved in building the querystring, that is composed in the page ? Actually, it is not possible to help like it is now.